# How to make a static image appear after 3 seconds?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How would I make an image appear after 3 seconds?

Comment: How would i do it automatically?

Comment: Xcode 4 is just an IDE, and Objective C is just a language - you are probably talking about either Mac OS X programming (Cocoa) or iPhone/iPad (iOS, CocoaTouch) perhaps ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
[self performSelector: withObject: afterDelay: ]
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm a big fan of using GCD (iOS 4+) because you can simplify your code with inline blocks.

In your case, you should set the image to hidden in Interface Builder, then create an IBOutlet with a connection to an ivar in your class.

Then you can simply run this in `viewDidLoad` or similar:

```
dispatch_time_t delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_SEC * 3.0); 
dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    yourImage.hidden = NO;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that you are calling performSelector:withObject:afterDelay from the main thread, and that your UIImageView is initially hidden.

```
//assumes theImageView.hidden = YES
[self performSelector:@selector(showImage:) withObject:theImageView afterDelay:yourTimeInterval];

-(void)showImage:(UIImageView*)anImageView {
    anImageView.hidden = NO;
}
```

It is important that performSelector is called from the main thread because the selector that is called after the delay will run on the same thread, and you do not want to update UI from anything other than the main thread as a general rule.

Comment: Actually, `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` schedules a timer to fire after the delay. It does not pause the thread it's called on, and generally won't even run correctly on a worker thread (because they rarely have run loops set up.)

Comment: @Steve: I don't think that `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` runs as a background thread, does it?  It just runs on the **current** thread, which in this case would most likely be the main thread.

Comment: Did I say performSelector:withObject:afterDelay blocked?  Your point about the run loop, however, is well taken (I can't say I know much about that).

Comment: @sudo - You are probably right, that seems to make sense.  In that case, showImageDelayed: can be skipped for showImage: which is nicer.

Comment: @Steve, can you please edit your answer? This will be very misguiding for beginners.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used XCode in awhile, but I'll take a stab for ya..

1. In your Interface Builder set the image's visibility as hidden
2. When your app starts up, set some global variable to the current time in an init fxn
3. In the main control loop for your UI, check if that global var contains a time that is more than 3 seconds ago, if so, change that image's visibility parameter to shown.

Best I can really say without really taking a look, which isn't possible right now.

Good luck!

Comment: Polling for a timeout? This is crazy!

Comment: Indeed, a crappy solution. Though conceptually trivial. But yes, you are right, there are certainly much better solutions. From sudo's post, it looks like there are even built-in methods for this, which would seem ideal. I suppose you could do a nicer job by configuring a timer ISR (I mean a hardware timer, which is embedded systems style thinking) and then using that. But indeed, I admit, my solution is only nice in that it it's very simple, it's also super ugly and somewhat inefficient.