# Adding delay to UIButton

Tags: button, view, delay

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a static image appear after 3 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429935/how-to-make-a-static-image-appear-after-3-seconds)

I want to be able to push the button, 3 seconds later it will switch to the next view. With Objective C, iOS, xcode4.

Comment: The answer to this is the same as the answer to the question you asked yesterday: [How to make an image appear after 3 seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429935/how-to-make-a-static-image-appear-after-3-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(myMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

... of course replacing your method's name for the selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a Timer when the Button is clicked. It should be implemented in the event handler of the Button

[NSTimer Class Refernce](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)